# Unable to display properly charset ibm850 in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, encoding

I have some HTML file generated by an old software. It writes files in cp850 (aka ibm850). It puts this at the top of the file:

```
<HEAD>
<META http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=ibm850">
```

The file is itself writing to disk using cp850 encoding (i.e. if I open it in Notepad++ for example, it's properly recognized as such).

In Internet Explorer, this file shows properly. In Firefox 46, I get some wrong characters. For example, I get `ÄÄ` instead of `──`.

I tried various aliases for IBM850 per the [Mozilla CharSet Aliases document](https://wiki.mozilla.org/I18n:Charset_Aliases), but none worked.

Is that a problem in Firefox? Or is that a problem with the HTML? Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, Mozilla dropped support for CP850 4 years ago in version 19. A whole bunch of encodings were dropped as they were very old.

[Bug 846936 - Non-ASCII characters not displayed correctly in encoding IBM850 (and possibly others?)](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=846936)